# How to make a take-off/landing for an airplane in BGE?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

It is possible to do a take-off/landing for an airplane in BGE using logic bricks?

I've done it but on the floor the plane is not limited in rotation.

For take-off I'm applying a rotation around X, but if it is stationary I'm still able to rotate it.
Can I limit the rotation to 25 degrees until it has some distance from the floor?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that it has to be rigid body.
Sitting on the "ground" the the rigid body is respecting the physics laws so it is loosing 2 
DOF rotations.

Comment: If you solved the problem, can you detail as to exactly what was the problem or what you were doing wrong etc. A vague one liner isn't sufficient.